# How to transfer large files/directories over network using AsyncSocket

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ftp, asyncfileupload, cocoaasyncsocket

I've tried the NSTask > NSData method, but the CPU/memory overhead is extremely large for anything over 1GB, so I need to find a way to do this like, say, an FTP server does it.

EDIT: How does remote desktop's copy files do it?

Comment: I'll let someone else elaborate on an official answer, but the way I would solve a problem like this would be to have a maximum size (for a buffer, or a `NSData` object) and then do the transfer in sequential increments.

Comment: Since my app is a client-sever app, could I possible write an FTP server with single authentication, and have the clients connect to that on the side and download it?

Comment: Well sure... you can do any kind of file transfer you want (FTP, TCP, UDP, two tin cans tied together with a string, etc.).  As you're the programmer, you get to decide how best to implement file transfers.  :-)

Comment: HAHA, true that, but I'm trying to emulate how Remote Desktop does it... for example, if I were to install a package, i'd need to copy it over first, then i'd need to install. If I did the copy separately, then the install wouldn't work, and so on. The real question is how can I do it (the tasks) serially without hanging, or CPU overload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it. I had to read it into the memory in small byte-size (HAHA GET THE PUN?) pieces and transfer it over that way. Keep in mind that this only works for files, not directories. I tested it on a 450MB file and it copied in about 3 minutes with the exact same byte count as the source. It was a video, and while I was streaming it to the client, I was able to play it as well. Nifty, huh?

Without further ado, here's the code I used, slightly patched up to do a simple file-copy instead of over the network.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"/path/to/file/dest" contents:nil attributes:nil];
NSFileHandle *output = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"/path/to/file/dest"];

uint64 offset = 0;
uint32 chunkSize = 8192;


NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"/path/to/file/source"];
NSAutoreleasePool *autoreleasePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSData *data = [handle readDataOfLength:chunkSize];

NSLog(@"Entering Loop.");

while ([data length] > 0) {
    [output seekToEndOfFile];
    [output writeData:data];
    offset += [data length];

    NSLog(@"Switching Loop.");

    [autoreleasePool release];
    autoreleasePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [handle seekToFileOffset:offset];
    data = [handle readDataOfLength:chunkSize];
}

NSLog(@"Exited Loop.");

[handle closeFile];
[autoreleasePool release];

[output closeFile];
[output release];
```

Comment: You can also modify the chunkSize to fit your memory-hogging needs. :D The NSLog()s should probably be removed since they overkill Xcode's CPU usage.

Comment: what is this:uint64 offset = 0;
uint32 chunkSize = 8192;